# Динамический imageview

Tags: android, java

Вставляю картинку в ImageView, картинка иногда меняется. Почему-то  с некоторыми картинками появляются отступы сверху где-то 20dp и снизу столько же, а с некоторыми нормально. Картинки бывают разных размеров. Появляются именно отступы, это не картинки с белым фоном сверху и снизу, бывают картинки и с отступом где-то по 40dp.

Ведь, по идее, она должна заполняться на ширину, и потом картинка вписывается на высоту.

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/snow">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="radioGroupInvisible"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_lateral_menu">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
layout_width="match_parent"
android:saleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Атрибут *android:adjustViewBounds* укажет, что размеры ImageView должны быть изменены под размеры картинки.

Comment: @Алексей Илларионов спасибо, помогло, интересно, почему она по умолчанию так не делает, ведь по логике так и должно быть, контейнет image подстраивается под картинку, если указано wrap_content.

Answer (score 2):

[android:scaleType](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imageview.php) - тип растягивания картинки в контейнере. Плюс можно поставить у ImageView св-во

```
layout_width="match_parent" это растянет контейнер по всей ширине.
```

Comment: @nekaneka нет не помогло, добавил скриншот, с разными картинками, по разному заполняет высоту,

Comment: @nekaneka а когда я ставлю android:scaleType="fitStart" пространства сверху не остается но но это пустое пространство которое было вверху переместилоись  вниз, то есть пустое пространство ниже стало в два раза больше

Comment: Вам нужно полное заполнение контейнера, без полос?

Comment: @nekaneka с некоторыми картинками строка "ОПЕРАТОР" находится сразу под картинкой без отступов, так мне и нужно, чтобы не было отступов, а что за полосы вы имеете в виду?